# Twitter Bootstrap in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, rubygems

I generated views using this command

```
rails g bootstrap:themed Todo
```

it generated several views for my model.

I am using git and reverted the project to its former branch without the boostrap.

Now, I am trying to regenerate the views but it always returns this

```
   identical  app/views/manifests/index.html.erb
```

How do I force the bootstap generator to regenerate the views for my project?

TIA

Comment: did you try `rails d bootstrap:themed Todo`?

Comment: yes I've tried it and issued the `rails g bootstrap:themed Todo` again, but It doesn't show the generated files on my project

Comment: When you run the generate command, you should see a line on the terminal for each generated file.  Do you see these (like you previously did)?  If so, do you just need to refresh your file view?  If not, what do you see instead (just some generated file messages?  none?).

Comment: Yes I see the create prompts like this `create  app/views/todo/index.html.erb` I even went to the directory app/views/, but unfortunately even the directory wasn't there.

Comment: At least in my IDE, the directory tree may need to be refreshed before the files appear.  Is that possibly the case for you as well?

Comment: I've already refreshed and restarted my IDE, but to no luck :(

Comment: Last guesses for me - you are running the generate in the wrong project by mistake or refreshing/viewing the wrong project by mistake.  Other than that, hopefully someone else can help you.

Comment: Thanks for everything, I am not sure how this gem references my project. One thing that I am sure is I issue the command to generate bootstrap on my project's root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to work it out by moving my project into another directory, preferably into a different folder.